# Backend/frontend/API naming convention

Tags: rest, api, architecture, naming, conventions

For example, we have 2 microservices written by Java, C#.
Front-end with Typescript.
Java uses camel case and has one GET with query params and JSON response,
C# uses pascal case and has one GET with query params and JSON response.
TypeScript uses camel case and both GETs.

first question is:
Do we need use different cases for query params and JSON inside GET (C# - pascal case and Java - camel case) or we need to use one convention for all sources?
Also query params and JSON must have the same cases, mustn't it?

second question is:
If I have already had some API with query params and JSON in pascal case. Need I to write some "normalizer" to map pascal case to camel case?
Just from my point of view, frontend, backend and API can have different conventions but developers need to map data which is coming from other place. But it can be overweight to write many "serializations" on frontend for all data from API.

From my experience I developed the project there all parts used camel case, but also I developed the app where backend and API used pascal case and frontend used camel case but I had some issues from the last one.

Just want to see your opinion about this theme and know how do you make it? Would be glad to see your own examples and experiences. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

We had the same question in the project I am working on right now, several weeks ago and considered those points:

1. We wanted 'public facing' entities to have the same convention (endpoints, JSON DTOs etc.)
2. We wanted to distinguish between functions/methods and variables
3. We don't wanted to influence the learned behaviour inside a technology

We further considered that snake_case is better readable by humans then camelCase or PascalCase (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case#Readability_studies).

So we agreed on keys in JSONs being snake_case for readability as well as variable names as long as the language is not much opinionated on that (i.e. we adopted snake_case for JavaScript, but not for Java).

Further we agreed on endpoints being camelCase, since it is a method/function like construct. We chose camelCase over PascalCase, since PascalCase could be misleading in regards to classnames typically being PascalCase. We even took camelCase for JavaScript functions.

That works out fine so far. Hope that helps.

Comment: So, as I got, your decision was: 
Backend maps JSON from their convention to API convention and frontend uses the same convention as API.
Also, does backend get query params with PascalCase and maps it to its own convention?